# How to change innerHTML according to a variable, which are combination of two parts with one part changing over time

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, innerhtml

My code shows below. 
I want to increase count in js when user click on "next", and use the combination of the fixed expression "text" and the changing variable "count" as a var to pass to innerHTML.
I tried 'text'+count, "'text'+count" and so on, none of those worked. Any suggestions?
Thanks!!!

```
<script>
var count = 1
text1 = "feature 1 content"
text2 = "feature 2 content"
text3 = "feature 3 content"

function slideForward()
{
    count = count + 1
    if (count == 4){
        count = 1;}
    document.getElementById('featureShow').innerHTML="text"+count ;
}
</script>

<div id="popUpDivFeatures">
    <p id="featureShow">feature 1 content</p>
    <a href="JavaScript:slideBackward()">Back</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:slideForward()">Next</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array instead:

```
var count = 1

var text = new Array();
text[1] = "feature 1 content";
text[2] = "feature 2 content";
text[3] = "feature 3 content";
function slideForward()
{
    count = count + 1
    if (count == 4){
        count = 1;}
    document.getElementById('featureShow').innerHTML=text[count] ;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hewC/

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your logic there a bit such as:

```
var text = "feature " + count + " content";
```

Comment: This is a great idea. However I decide to take Ryan's approach just in case the content of the each text will be something else.